# Displaying an image from Desktop Path

Tags: python, image, desktop, reader

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage

def loadImages(path):
    # return array of images

    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        loadedImages.append(img)

    return loadedImages

path = r"C:\Users\Aidan\Desktop\APDR_PDhh_epi5new.bmp"

# your images in an array
imgs = loadImages(path)

for img in imgs:
    # you can show every image
    img.show()
```

> NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid:
>   'C:\Users\Aidan\Desktop\APDR_PDhh_epi5new.bmp'

Above is the error.

I have the bitmap file named "APDR_PDhh_epi5new.bmp" on my desktop and I am getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `listdir` on `path`, but `C:\Users\Aidan\Desktop\APDR_PDhh_epi5new.bmp` is not a directory. It's a file. Try providing a directory for `path`. Additionally, you ought to use `os.path.join` to create the argument to `open`, rather than using string concatenation.

```
import os
from PIL import Image as PImage

def loadImages(path):
    # return array of images

    imagesList = os.listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(os.path.join(path,image))
        loadedImages.append(img)

    return loadedImages

path = r"C:\Users\Aidan\Desktop"

# your images in an array
imgs = loadImages(path)
print(imgs)
for img in imgs:
    # you can show every image
    img.show()
```